# WKHTMLtoPDF load CSS and Media files

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to use images stored in the `MEDIA` folder in the PDF
I'm using a code:

```
<img src"{{MEDIA_URL}}{{booking.photo.path}}">
```

This loads a broken image in the generated PDF.

Additionally the bootstrap which i am attempting to load from cdn also doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**I seem to have figured it out...**

Instead of : `<img src"{{MEDIA_URL}}{{booking.photo.path}}">`
When I use `<img src"http://127.0.0.1:800/media/{{booking.photo.path}}">`then it works!

**http://127.0.0.1:8000 is my localhost address.**